# Smartgit : not a DIRC file error

Tags: smartgit

Today when I first tried to open a repository in Smartgit, it threw *Executing a command failed "not a DIRC file"* error. No idea what it means. I haven't done anything fancy besides pushing changes to bitbucket and now I cannot do that because it won't even open the repository.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Be sure to back up your local changes (or better the entire repository), get rid of `.git/index` and in in your repository root run `git reset --hard`.

Comment: I just got this after a power outage :(

Comment: @endolith, same 

Comment: Deleting `.git/index` and running `git reset --hard` did *NOT* work for me.

Comment: I have fixed same issue with SmartGit 21.2.4 by deleting ./git/index file, open SmartGit software myProject  project, checkout to other branch(develop or master) and run pull command, checkout to same branch and merge changes from other branch(develop or master).

Comment: I just got this after a blue screen :(

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by deleting the `/.git/index` file in your repo and then running `git reset` in cmd in the repo root directory. It'll take 5+ minutes to perform as it rescans the entire repo. Any uncommitted changed files *should* survive this but if any of the above doesn't work use `git reset --hard` which will destroy any uncommitted files.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this - was a submodule that the reference too had become corrupted and it wasn't displaying as an existing submodule at all in SmartGit.

I deleted the submodule folder in the explorer, SmartGit then showed it as deleted, I then reset that submodule it to pull it down again, checked out a proper branch to fix it being a detached head and from there everything worked.